# SQL - for each entry in a table - check for associated row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a log table which logs a start row, and a finish row for a particular event.

Each event should have a start row, and if everything goes ok it should have an end row.

But if something goes wrong then the end row may not be created.

I want to `SELECT` everything in the table that has a start row but not an associated end row.

For example, consider the table like this:

```
id  event_id  event_status
1     123           1
2     123           2
3     234           1
4     234           2
5     456           1
6     678           1
7     678           2
```

Notice that the id column 5 has a start row but no end row.  Start is an event_status of 1, end is an event_status of 2.

How can i pull back all the event_ids which have a start row but not an end row>?

This is for mssql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `not exists` subquery to demand that no other row exists that ends the event:

```
select  *
from    YourTable t1
where   status = 1
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable t2
        where   t2.event_id = t1.event_id
                and t2.status = 2
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with left self join as below:

```
select y1.event_id from #yourevents y1 left join #yourevents y2
    on y1.event_id = y2.event_id
    and y1.event_status = 1
    and y2.event_status = 2
    where y2.event_id is null
        and y1.event_status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you could use one of 3 solutions:

**Solution 1. The classic**
Check if there is no end status

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM myTable t2 
    WHERE t1.event_id = t2.event_id AND t2.status=2
)
```

**Solution 2. Make it pretty. Don't do subqueries with so many parentheses**
The same check, but in a more concise and pretty manner

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM myTable t1
LEFT JOIN myTable t2 ON t1.event_id = t2.event_id AND t2.status=2
-- Doesn't exist
WHERE t2.event_id IS NULL
```

**Solution 3. Look for the last status for each event**
More flexibility in case the status logic becomes more complicated

```
WITH last_status AS (
SELECT
  id,
  event_id,
  status,
  -- The ROWS BETWEEN ..yadda yadda ... FOLLOWING might be unnecessary. Try, check.
  last_value(status) OVER (PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY status ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS last_status
FROM myTable 
)
SELECT
  id,
  event_id,
  status
FROM last_events
WHERE last_status<>2
```

There are more, with min/max queries and others. Pick what best suits your need for cleanliness, readability and versatility.